# Direction of Force on a Dipole in a given Electric field

Tags: forces, electrostatics, electric-fields, dipole, dipole-moment

How should I determine the direction of the force in the given case: (p is the electric dipole moment)
[image]

Using the following formula

[image]

My book has the following :

[image]

I am unable to understand the given correlation between the direction of Force and the formula. I am confused with the gradient of E and it's dot product (correct me if I am wrong) with p .

Comment: Please don't close the question as it is not any homework problem. I just need some help with the formula.

Comment: Is this a high-school book? $p$ is supposed to be a vector. It’s bizarre that $\mathbf F$ and $\mathbf E$ are but $p$ isn’t. What is $l$ supposed to be?

Comment: Yes it's a high school book. I think p instead of **P** is a printing error. Idk about l but does it matter? We have the p vector and I am just asking for direction of Force.

Comment: $l$ has to be the distance along the direction of $\mathbf p$.

Comment: I’m used to seeing $\mathbf F=(\mathbf p\cdot\nabla)\mathbf E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take advantage of the fact that $\vec p$ is a vector.

Resolve $\vec p$ into two components - $\vec p_1$ and $\vec p_2$ one along the line joining charge $q$ and the centre of dipole and one perpendicular to it *(ref fig 1)*. the

Electric field at an axial point of dipole : $\vec E_{axial}= \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{2p_2}{r^3}$

Electric Field along the equitorial plane : $\vec E_{eq}= \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{p_1}{r^3}$

Now, the net electric field at $q$ is $\vec E=\vec E_{eq}+\vec E_{axial}$ and force on $q$ is just $q\vec E$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Think of a “finite-size dipole” as a positive charge at the tip of the $\mathbf p$ vector and an equal negative charge at the tail. The forces exerted by $q$ on these two charges will not be exactly equal and opposite, because the field of $q$ isn’t uniform and the two charges aren’t at the same point. Draw the two force vectors and add them to get the net force on the dipole.